# Select filtered data and delete to last visible row excluding header

Tags: vba, excel

I have data and done some filtering. Right now I want to delete entire rows up to the last visible row. Also, I do not want to include my header (row 5) in this case. I am not sure how I should work around with the code below:

```
Dim row1 As Variant
row1 = Rows(5).Offset(1, 0)
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Rows("row1:" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Replace `"row1:"` with `row1 & “:"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an Error Handler whenever working with SpecialCells.

```
Sub DeleteVisibleRows()
    With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
        .Range("A5", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(1).EntireRow _
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I understand why a need for error handler? Thanks for the code Btw!

Comment: `SpecialCells` will throw an error if it doesn't find any cells.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try...

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A6:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Try this if you only want to delete the visible rows if you have applied a filter on the data set.

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A6:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
    Sub test()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Rows("6:" & lastrow)

    rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    End Sub
```